# Open a .jar with JDK 12 in Ubuntu 18

Tags: 18.04, java, jdk, openjdk

I have applications that require the JDK-12 of Java. I used to run my applications in the OpenJDK Java 8 Runtime (those were SWIFT applications, so all I had to do, was double click on them). But now, I have to install the new JDK in order to run this application. But, they automatically open with Archive Manager.

I'm pretty sure that I installed JDK 12 and later tried out JAVA alone. I tried using the old OpenJDK 8 but of course it cannot open my applications for Java 12.

How can I run my applications in the new Ubuntu 18 with JDK-12?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to check if JAVA is installed and what version of JAVA you're using:

`update-java-alternatives -l` shows you all the Java versions you have installed.

`java -version` shows you the Java version you are using.

`java -showversion` shows you the Java version you are using and help.

However, it seems like you probably don't have JAVA(JDK 12) installed, that's why the `.jar` file is opening with Archive Manager. Still, try right clicking on the `.jar` file and select the Java Runtime Enivornment to run the file.

Comment: Yes, i do have Java installed and of course that commands show me the version that i have. I guess i will recompile all the applications to Java 8